# What is the best way to index many-to-many relationship in mongodb?

Tags: performance, mongodb, indexing

I have two entities. User and Item with many to many relationship. I will read/query

1. items by user id - 50% of time
2. users by item id - 50% of time

Writing performance dosn't matter.

How should I store those data for best performance?

1. `user:{id:1, items:[1,2,3,4,5]}` and index by items
2. similar for items i.e. `item:{id:1, users:[1,2,3,4,5]}`
3. duplicate data and indexes only by id i.e. u`ser:{id:1, items:[1,2,3,4,5]} and item:{id:1, users:[1,2,3,4,5]}`

Comment: without knowing how your app works it's tough to make the best distinction on this; what are you using the most? how does your app work? where are your reads? where are your writes?

Comment: As i have written, I will use reading(querying) by user_id and by item_id same time. Writing performance doesn't metter - it is very rare operation.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the relation should be stored similarly to how you would do it in a relational DB.  You'll have 3 collections: one for users, one for items, and a relation collection where each document has just one user-item relation.

Thus any query to get the users for an item or vise-versa will require two queries, one to the relation collection and one to the "target" collection.  This is definitely one of those situations that a RDBMS does better, but for most people it's a fair trade-off and if you have MongoDB setup correctly the two queries should still be very fast.

I would not recommend duplicating data, aside from the increased storage requirements, in an ideal world it would work but you're likely to end up with consistency issues.